# HOW should I do running intervals for martial arts?

Tags: running, training, martial-arts

**TL;DR: Exactly HOW should I do running intervals to supplement Muay Thai?**

I'm a relative beginner at Muay Thai (and, compared to many people here, a casual one who only trains 2X/week) and am interested in adding more conditioning work to my non-training days. I think my level of conditioning is currently not too bad, since I seem to have good staying power in class. Before taking up Muay Thai, I was doing various forms of cardio including (at various points) boxing, swimming, and treadmill intervals. The treadmill intervals had been 60 sec on/60 off for 8-9 rounds, where the "on" part was running ~7.8 mph at a 10% incline and the "off" part was brisk walking also at a 10% incline.

I am specifically interested in running-based intervals because 1) it's convenient (the Muay Thai gym is far away, so training more often isn't possible right now), and 2) I am also lifting (Starting Strength), which I need desperately, and feel that barbell-based conditioning will interfere more than running.

I found some other great existing answers on this topic, but none address the 4 more specific questions I am about to ask:

- [Something about cardio in general](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/219/rule-1-cardio-what-exercises-are-worth-doing-to-increase-cardiovascular-fitnes/270#270)
- [Something about intervals in general](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7907/what-are-practical-guidelines-for-effective-interval-training/7909#7909)
- [Something about running for BJJ](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2963/how-should-a-bjj-practitioner-run)

Here are the parameters I need advice on:

## 1.) Session length

For example, 7 minutes of intense hill sprinting? Or 20 minutes of something less grueling?

## 2.) Work : rest time ratio

Equal work and rest? Tabata? etc.

## 3.) Work : rest intensity ratio

To use the limiting cases, should I run some short distance like a mile as fast as possible at a steady speed? Alternate all-out sprinting and walking? Or somewhere in between?

## 4.) Hills/incline vs. flat

Self-explanatory.

Comment: Pleasantly surprised to see starting strength.

Comment: You need to describe what you're looking for.  Are you looking to have more explosiveness?  More endurance?  Faster recovery?  Cross training to prevent injury?....

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert, but in lieu of one, what I do for interval training is to warm up for about three tenths of a mile, then alternate sprinting and jogging/walking each tenth of a mile for two or three miles, 20 or 30 minutes.  That seems to help me a lot.

For your format: 
1) Session length: 20-30 minutes of interval sprinting on level terrain
2) Equal work/rest ratio
3) Sprinting as fast as possible and alternating with jogging/walking, so a high intensity ratio
4) Flat.  Hills complicate the issue.

Good luck.